# get wrong inverse matrix from both solve() and ginv()

Tags: r, matrix, inverse

`I am trying to get an inverse matrix of

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]    1    rou   0
[2,]  rou  1+rou^2 rou
[3,]    0    rou   1
```

the inverse matrix calculated by hand should be

```
                 1     rou  rou^2
 1/(1-rou)       rou    1   rou
                 rou^2 rou   1
```

Take rou=0.3 as an example

`a=matrix(c(1,0.3,0,0.3,1.09,0.3,0,0.3,1),nrow=3)`

`a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0 0.30  0.0
[2,]  0.3 1.09  0.3
[3,]  0.0 0.30  1.0`

Its inverse matrix calculated by hand is the following matrix

```
      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.0989011  0.3296703  0.0989011
[2,]  0.3296703  1.0989011 0.3296703
[3,]  0.0989011  0.3296703  1.0989011
```

by using `solve(a)` or `ginv(a)` in R, I got

```
   [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.0989011 -0.3296703  0.0989011
[2,] -0.3296703  1.0989011 -0.3296703
[3,]  0.0989011 -0.3296703  1.0989011
```

I am wondering why there are negative signs. Had anyone met this problem before? How to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Follow up: I checked a%*%solve(a) and it is

```
          [,1]      [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.000000e+00    0    0
[2,] -6.938894e-18    1    0
[3,]  0.000000e+00    0    1
```

Follow up 2:
I found my mistake is that I forgot to add the negative signs for some elements when calculating cofactor matrix

Comment: Have you considered that your math might be off? Have you checked that  `a %*% your_inverse` is close to the identity? `a %*% solve(a)` is.

Comment: R is not Mathematica. Use a different tool if you want symbolic algebra.

Comment: No, you don't wanna invert a matrix. http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/

Answer (score 5):

I think you made a mistake in your hand calculations. This is the correct result:

[image]

Click [here](http://wolfr.am/29tBsbw-) for an easy way to make these sort of calculations.

Comment: but this is not consistent with R output as well:(

Comment: @Yukun But it is!  It's a numerical result, so you can expect some error.  7e-18 is very small.

Comment: check out `?zapsmall` too